# Cannot able to verify a signed data

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature, smartcard, digital-certificate, cryptoapi

Through smart card using a tool, I am signing data "Hello".

The output what i am getting is in hex format.

`14 5F 65 CE 7C 2D 8A 0A FA B0 FB 86 CE 28 90 84 
37 2D 04 63 B2 35 FA 40 4A B6 35 C8 90 AF 55 7F 
B1 CA FE FD 5B F9 1B 7C DB 74 63 BF 16 5B B3 6D 
E8 2D B6 D7 2E 90 AF 0A 5E CF 78 73 E3 37 02 C2 
97 0E F9 B3 40 4C 67 CD E4 7C D9 4B D3 C9 86 51 
8E 1E 84 81 B4 30 AC 68 96 59 CB 63 E5 C8 28 48 
C7 1D E8 E9 FC E8 C9 BE 36 33 0A F0 A9 35 C4 D4 
BF 60 66 21 5C 41 8F 48 91 D4 BB AF 75 75 7A B3 
2A 8A 28 B8 30 D1 B4 6B 69 23 82 2D 28 77 30 05 
D5 C9 AB 41 17 C1 68 6D D9 80 0F F2 C1 FC 32 6E 
22 61 27 97 9C DD C3 50 33 AA DB F4 BA 98 29 FA 
4F E2 B4 BC C5 9E 90 34 F3 BC 3D 78 01 47 AF 96 
20 06 6F F9 41 30 D7 35 52 D3 DE 85 E3 FE 0B B7 
15 4D 1A 73 B8 36 F4 A1 59 A2 7E 05 50 8B 52 AC 
B4 EF 2D D9 29 9D D9 BB C8 DF F3 67 C5 D1 D9 C0 
0C 65 68 A8 12 9B 24 92 4E EB 98 D8 B0 D9 2E 6A`

The respective signed data in string format I have saved in file signedData.txt.

```
._eÎ|-Š.ú°û†Î(„7-.c²5ú@J¶5È¯U±Êþý[ù.|Ûtc¿.[³mè-¶×.¯.^Ïxsã7.Â—.ù³@LgÍä|ÙKÓÉ†QŽ.„´0¬h– YËcåÈ(HÇ.èéüèÉ¾63.ð©5ÄÔ¿`f!\AH‘Ô»¯uuz³*Š(¸0Ñ´ki#‚-(w0.ÕÉ«A.ÁhmÙ€.òÁü2n"a'—œÝÃP3ªÛôº˜)úOâ ´¼Åž4ó¼=x.G¯– .oùA0×5RÓÞ…ãþ.·.M.s¸6ô¡Y¢~.P‹R¬´ï-Ù)Ù»ÈßógÅÑÙÀ.eh¨.›$’Në˜Ø°Ù.j
```

I am using **Windows CryptoAPI** for verification of this signed data.

I am opening the file signedData.txt and writing the data into the buffer "
signedBuffer"

Then i am finding my certificate from the store and taking the handle of public key using

`hPubKey = CryptImportPublicKeyInfo(hProv, ENCODING_TYPE,      &pCertContext->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo, &hCertPubKey);`

Then I am creating a hash object using CALG_SHA_256

`hObject = CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, &hHashObject);`

Then adding my data with the hash object

`CryptHashData(hhObject, Buffer, BufferLen, 0); // char Buffer = "Hello";`

```
                                       // int BufferLen = strlen(Buffer );
```

In the last step i am verifying the signature using

`CryptVerifySignature(hObject,signedBuffer,signedBufferBytes,hPubKey,NULL,0); /* signedBuffer contains  signed data in string format */`

`/*signedBufferBytes has no. of bytes in the buffer */`

but this signed data is not verified. Error code i am getting is `0x80090006 - Invalid Signature`.

Public key In hex format is :

`30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 b8 f8 dc 2c a5 03 84 
ba 72 c6 0e 03 89 51 6f 39 a8 41 e3 49 b3 f7 14 
31 d3 43 b7 fc 1f 61 c2 43 b0 77 9e 19 af f4 8b 
02 99 72 c1 17 21 1d 23 da ab 53 54 74 33 e4 ab 
9d 82 d2 68 33 9a b5 9c 99 cb f0 12 e0 f8 44 4f 
e8 91 3f 60 ed ca fa 3b 40 bd 64 50 92 d3 c2 c1 
48 ad 24 3e ca 64 2c 50 a9 01 b5 9f f4 a4 46 e5 
84 e9 a4 87 41 86 a1 7a 7f fc a6 f0 e0 b1 de f0 
c1 f2 5d c8 84 16 15 4d e4 df 43 43 3a cd ad ec 
eb af 1b 9c a7 5c 40 dc ae 1f 71 6e a4 c6 0f dd 
3e 3c c8 0d 25 4c 61 74 df aa ed b5 d5 b9 06 6a 
8e b0 b7 c0 e6 c9 bf db b1 07 2e a2 76 aa e7 28 
1c 8d 32 4e b3 58 1d 34 89 96 ed 3e da 29 e0 1e 
c9 c2 2e 18 19 a6 ba 91 32 b7 85 97 87 92 16 c5 
01 b4 4f 57 5c 56 1b f5 f4 6a 29 6b 2e 51 8b f5 
4c 6f b8 fd cb 09 d9 fd 66 09 04 49 b6 ba 7e d0 
af 70 3a 51 41 5a a5 04 bf 02 03 01 00 01`

The Signature buffer now I am using is:

```
BYTE            bSignatureBuf[]     = {
        0x6A, 0x2E, 0xD9, 0xB0, 0xD8, 0x98, 0xEB, 0x4E, 0x92, 0x24, 0x9B, 0x12, 0xA8, 0x68, 0x65, 0x0C,
        0xC0, 0xD9, 0xD1, 0xC5, 0x67, 0xF3, 0xDF, 0xC8, 0xBB, 0xD9, 0x9D, 0x29, 0xD9, 0x2D, 0xEF, 0xB4,
        0xAC, 0x52, 0x8B, 0x50, 0x05, 0x7E, 0xA2, 0x59, 0xA1, 0xF4, 0x36, 0xB8, 0x73, 0x1A, 0x4D, 0x15,
        0xB7, 0x0B, 0xFE, 0xE3, 0x85, 0xDE, 0xD3, 0x52, 0x35, 0xD7, 0x30, 0x41, 0xF9, 0x6F, 0x06, 0x20,
        0x96, 0xAF, 0x47, 0x01, 0x78, 0x3D, 0xBC, 0xF3, 0x34, 0x90, 0x9E, 0xC5, 0xBC, 0xB4, 0xE2, 0x4F,
        0xFA, 0x29, 0x98, 0xBA, 0xF4, 0xDB, 0xAA, 0x33, 0x50, 0xC3, 0xDD, 0x9C, 0x97, 0x27, 0x61, 0x22,
        0x6E, 0x32, 0xFC, 0xC1, 0xF2, 0x0F, 0x80, 0xD9, 0x6D, 0x68, 0xC1, 0x17, 0x41, 0xAB, 0xC9, 0xD5,
        0x05, 0x30, 0x77, 0x28, 0x2D, 0x82, 0x23, 0x69, 0x6B, 0xB4, 0xD1, 0x30, 0xB8, 0x28, 0x8A, 0x2A,
        0xB3, 0x7A, 0x75, 0x75, 0xAF, 0xBB, 0xD4, 0x91, 0x48, 0x8F, 0x41, 0x5C, 0x21, 0x66, 0x60, 0xBF,
        0xD4, 0xC4, 0x35, 0xA9, 0xF0, 0x0A, 0x33, 0x36, 0xBE, 0xC9, 0xE8, 0xFC, 0xE9, 0xE8, 0x1D, 0xC7,
        0x48, 0x28, 0xC8, 0xE5, 0x63, 0xCB, 0x59, 0x96, 0x68, 0xAC, 0x30, 0xB4, 0x81, 0x84, 0x1E, 0x8E,
        0x51, 0x86, 0xC9, 0xD3, 0x4B, 0xD9, 0x7C, 0xE4, 0xCD, 0x67, 0x4C, 0x40, 0xB3, 0xF9, 0x0E, 0x97,
        0xC2, 0x02, 0x37, 0xE3, 0x73, 0x78, 0xCF, 0x5E, 0x0A, 0xAF, 0x90, 0x2E, 0xD7, 0xB6, 0x2D, 0xE8,
        0x6D, 0xB3, 0x5B, 0x16, 0xBF, 0x63, 0x74, 0xDB, 0x7C, 0x1B, 0xF9, 0x5B, 0xFD, 0xFE, 0xCA, 0xB1,
        0x7F, 0x55, 0xAF, 0x90, 0xC8, 0x35, 0xB6, 0x4A, 0x40, 0xFA, 0x35, 0xB2, 0x63, 0x04, 0x2D, 0x37,
        0x84, 0x90, 0x28, 0xCE, 0x86, 0xFB, 0xB0, 0xFA, 0x0A, 0x8A, 0x2D, 0x7C, 0xCE, 0x65, 0x5F, 0x14
    };
```

Comment: Are you reading and writing the data from the file as a string? Don't do that, because it's not text data.

Comment: Yes. I am using the signedData.txt file, from that file i am writing data into the signedBuffer. This signedBuffer i am using for the verification purpose.

Comment: You should treat the signed data as binary data; not all binary data represents valid character encoding. If you want to have text, you should first convert it to base 64 (and back to binary by decoding the base 64 data of course).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not treat your binary data as text, as given in the comments.

Even more important is that your signature has been generated using PKCS#1 SHA-1 and your hash function specifies SHA-256 - *presumably* using PKCS#1 [^1]. You have to use identical hash function during signature generation and verification.

You can see the hash function used by looking up the OID in the ASN.1 description after decrypting your signature with the public key (in case you are wondering how to find out the hash function used).

Also note this little remark from the API:

> The native cryptography API uses little-endian byte order (ed: for the signature bytes)

note that the non-M$ world uses big-endian byte order.

[^1]: as usual Microsoft does not specify the exact protocols they are applying [^2]

[^2]: this should view correctly once stackoverflow makes the tiny effort to implement markdown footnotes

Comment: Yes the hash algorithm is sha1. Ty for pointing it out. I have taken the signature in BYTE array format itself without converting it to string and also taken it in the reverse order. Also I have changed my hash algorithm to sha1, but still signature is not verified.

Comment: I think this sufficiently answers your question, unless you are expecting us to do a debug session with you (which we won't).

Comment: I have already verified the same signature using OpenSSL. But still I want to know why this signature is not verifying using CryptoAPI. BTW ty for all your help.